# Cannot connect to Tradfri light from raspberry pi

Tags: home-automation

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/controlling-ikea-tradfri-lights-from-your-pi) on the pi zero W to connect to Ikea Tradfri lights

Cannot connect using the following:

```
coap-client -m put -u "Client_identity" -k "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h" \
    -e '{ "3311": [{ "5850": 0 }] }' "coaps://192.168.0.10:5684/15001/65537"
```

following is the result:

```
v:1 t:CON c:PUT i:fac2 {} [ ]
```

but no light was turned off

I am very new to all this... Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the cure of your trouble....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554464/controlling-ikea-tradfri-lights-from-raspberry-pi/51758095

It solved mine.